# Communicate with webpage inside web view using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

Communicate with webpage inside web view using JavaScript and find html5 elements.
I've tried some code that execute JavaScript but i want to communicate with webpage or inspect webpage changes and elements inside webview using JavaScript like IDM extension , web browser extension. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Javascript Bridge like here:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html

or here:

https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/2014/06/12/putting-javascript-bridges-into-android-context/